# Why animation-iteration does't work with delay?

Tags: css, animation

I'm startin two css-animation one by one and use animation-delay for this. But then I write animation-iteration-count for animnation-1 and animation-2, it works for animation-2 only.
And I don't want to use %, from-to only.

```css
#body1 { 
    animation-name: animation-1, animation-2;
    animation-duration: 2s, 4s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2,2;
}
@keyframes animation-1 {
 from { transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); }
 to { transform: translate3d(0.5px, -.2px, 0px); }
}
@keyframes animation-2 {
 from { transform: translate3d(0.5px, -.2px, 0px); }
 to { transform: translate3d(0px, -0.5px, 0px); }
}
```

Comment: the delay is a multiplier of the duration so after some iteration they will overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animation-delay` property only delays the *initial* start of the animation, but after it's started it runs continuously.

Now, when the animation starts for the second time, it will not perform `animation-1` and only perform `animation-2` (Reason being `animation-2`'s animation declaration will be overwritten by `animation-1`, as both will be starting the same time).

You can get over this problem by using % values. This will not be possible by using just `from` and `to` values.

(That is, add a delay between the animation using `%` values).

A much better version of the code will be as follows): 
(Removing 2 animations and just letting one animation declaration do the job)

```
#body1 { 
    animation-name: animation-1;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
@keyframes animation-1 {
  0% { transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); }
  50% { transform: translate3d(0.5px, -.2px, 0px); }
  50% { transform: translate3d(0.5px, -.2px, 0px); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0px, -0.5px, 0px); }
}
```